# WSO2 SOAP reqest

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-micro-integrator

I'm send soap reqest to microservice and in respond I get this.

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>An error was detected in the Web Service request. (10894)</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <ns1:FaultDetail xmlns:ns1="urn:soap-fault:details">
                    <errorMessage>Error in SOAP Envelope: Content length must be specified. (10913)</errorMessage>
                    <requestID>----</requestID>
                </ns1:FaultDetail>
            </detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I create my soap envelope in payloadFactory.

```
<payloadFactory description="Set ARGS for CALL" media-type="xml">
        <format>
            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:xyz:zyz">
                <soapenv:Header/>
                <soapenv:Body>
                    ...
                </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>
        </format>
        <args>
            ...
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
```

Next I send this to microservice. Micro service work on SOAP 1.1. I'm don't attach content lenght because I do not know how.

Comment: does your soap envelope specify a content length?

Comment: You have not provided sufficient details to understand the issue. Please add all the details.  How do you create this? Where do you create this? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the PL factory and before sending the request try setting the following properties.

```xml
<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2" />
<property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
```